# Unable to connect to Azure sql database using JDBC - error with SSL

Tags: java, android-studio, ssl, jdbc, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect to my Azure sql database through a mobile app, using Android Studio.

```
String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://****.database.windows.net:1433;database=****;user=****@****;password=*****;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30";

public void connect(){

    Connection connection = null;

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is my code to connect to the database on Azure. The correct JDBC driver has been imported and I am using the correct username/password (marked in ***s).
I keep getting the same error regarding SSL which is as follows -

```
04-03 23:04:49.449 31439-31439/com.example.melissa.dbtest W/System.err: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Socket closed". ClientConnectionId:*****
04-03 23:04:49.452 31439-31439/com.example.melissa.dbtest W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2435)
04-03 23:04:49.452 31439-31439/com.example.melissa.dbtest W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1816)
04-03 23:04:49.452 31439-31439/com.example.melissa.dbtest W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2022)
04-03 23:04:49.452 31439-31439/com.example.melissa.dbtest W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1687)
04-03 23:04:49.452 31439-31439/com.example.melissa.dbtest W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1528)
04-03 23:04:49.452 31439-31439/com.example.melissa.dbtest W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:866)
04-03 23:04:49.452 31439-31439/com.example.melissa.dbtest W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:569)
04-03 23:04:49.452 31439-31439/com.example.melissa.dbtest W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
04-03 23:04:49.452 31439-31439/com.example.melissa.dbtest W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:237)
04-03 23:04:49.453 31439-31439/com.example.melissa.dbtest W/System.err:     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1753)
```

I've looked through so many answers and documents but I still can't seem to fix the problem. How can I connect to the Azure database using an SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try using JTDS driver instead

```
try {
        String SQL = "select * from dbo.Student";

        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = String.format("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://***.database.windows.net:1433/<your database name>;user=***;password=***;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
        }
        close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much this worked perfectly! Once I added the JTDS driver and changed the connection string it worked for me